# HSQL | Delete from db

Tags: variables, javafx, hsqldb, sql-delete

I am currently working on a small database with just 3 tables, that is displayed in a

```
javafx.TableView<Event>
```

Inserting something to the database works all fine with the SQLExpression

```
INSERT INTO events (name, location, numberOfGuests, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

, so I wanted to do the delete Expression similarly to this:

```
DELETE FROM events WHERE name = (name) AND location = (location) AND numberofguests = (numberOfGuests) AND date = (date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Of course, I needed to pack this to a preparedStatement:

```
    private static PreparedStatement getPrepStateFromEvent (Event e) throws SQLException {
    //--get the attributes of the event--//
    String eventName = e.getName();
    String location = e.getLocation();
    int numOfGuests = e.getNumberOfGuests();
    Date d = e.getDate();

    //--form a prepared statement--//
    PreparedStatement pstmnt = conn.prepareStatement(INSERT_INTO_EVENTS);

    //--enter values for the spaceholders in the pstmnt--//
    pstmnt.setString(1, eventName);
    pstmnt.setString(2, location);
    pstmnt.setInt(3, numOfGuests);
    pstmnt.setDate(4, d);

    //--return--//
    return pstmnt;
}
```

This works all fine with the insertion, but not with the deletion. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Your DELETE syntax is  wrong:

```
DELETE FROM events 
WHERE name = ?  
  AND location = ? 
  AND numberofguests = ? 
  AND date = ?
```

There is no `VALUES` clause, where did you see that strange syntax?

For future reference, the complete syntax is documented in the manual:
http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dataaccess-chapt.html#dac_delete_statement